# JavaScript for loop implementation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Good afternoon everyone.

I need a little help here, I have some repeat JavaScript code that I would like to condense, what I want to do is create a for loop with a count variable that increments the #DetailsBtn(i) replacing the number that is there and replacing it with the counter value of i.

Now I have not done much Javascript, and I am a C#/.Net and Java developer, but I would think that for loop should operate somewhat similiar. You can see what I am trying to replace with the number 79 and 80 references.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
$("#DetailsBtn79").click(function () {
    $("#DetailsRow79").toggleClass("gameRowOpen");
    $("#DetailsRow79 .leftDatePantherHolder").toggleClass("gameRowOpen");
    $("#DetailsRow79 .hgDate").toggleClass("gameRowOpen");
    $("#DetailsRow79 .hgGameTimeThemeGiveaway").toggleClass("gameRowOpen");
    $("#DetailsRow79 .hgGameTheme").toggleClass("gameRowOpen");
    $("#DetailsRow79 .hgMatchupBox").toggleClass("gameRowOpen");
    $("#DetailsRow79 .hgMKEWaveBox, #DetailsRow79 .hgOpponentBox").toggleClass("gameRowOpen");

    $("#DetailsRow79 .hgMatchupBoxExpanded").toggleClass("gameRowOpen");
    $("#DetailsRow79 .gameThemeAreaExpanded").toggleClass("gameRowOpen");
    });
    $('#DetailsBtn79').toggle(function () {
    $("#DetailsRow79 .ticketMasterGameLink").fadeIn();
    }, function () {
    $("#DetailsRow79 .ticketMasterGameLink").hide();
    });

$("#DetailsBtn80").click(function () {
    $("#DetailsRow80").toggleClass("gameRowOpen");
    $("#DetailsRow80 .leftDatePantherHolder").toggleClass("gameRowOpen");
    $("#DetailsRow80 .hgDate").toggleClass("gameRowOpen");
    $("#DetailsRow80 .hgGameTimeThemeGiveaway").toggleClass("gameRowOpen");
    $("#DetailsRow80 .hgGameTheme").toggleClass("gameRowOpen");
    $("#DetailsRow80 .hgMatchupBox").toggleClass("gameRowOpen");
    $("#DetailsRow80 .hgMKEWaveBox, #DetailsRow78 .hgOpponentBox").toggleClass("gameRowOpen");
    //$("#DetailsRow80 .ticketMasterGameLink").fadeToggle();
    $("#DetailsRow80 .hgMatchupBoxExpanded").toggleClass("gameRowOpen");
    $("#DetailsRow80 .gameThemeAreaExpanded").toggleClass("gameRowOpen");
    });
    $('#DetailsBtn80').toggle(function () {
    $("#DetailsRow80 .ticketMasterGameLink").fadeIn();
    }, function () {
    $("#DetailsRow80 .ticketMasterGameLink").hide();
    });
```

Comment: You could do it without a loop or oodles of repetitive code by using a jQuery selector that matches all of the elements, combined with $(this) and $().closest().

Comment: So, are you having some specific issue? Or is it just about coding hints?? If so, then you should probably go to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are trying to do is this:

Html:

```
<button class="DetailsBtn" id="DetailsBtn79">Button 79</button>
<button class="DetailsBtn" id="DetailsBtn80">Button 80</button>
```

Javascript:

```
$(".DetailsBtn").click(function(event)
{
    var btn = $(event.target);
    btn.toggleClass("gameRowOpen");
    // etc
});
```

To understand `id=""` vs `class=""` see http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_selectors.asp.

Comment: FYI [the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors) is a _much_ better reference than w3schools.  I'm glad they're slowly overtaking w3schools in search results...!

Comment: True. But while MDN is my go-to reference I find W3Schools' playground is a great learning tool.

Comment: It was, until all the sites like jsfiddle sprang up

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I would do.

First add a class to #DetailsBtn's, we'll call it .DetailsBtn.

New code will be:

```
$(".DetailsBtn").click(function () {
    var i = $(this).attr('id').replace('DetailsBtn', '');
    $("#DetailsRow"+i).toggleClass("gameRowOpen");
    $("#DetailsRow"+i+" .leftDatePantherHolder").toggleClass("gameRowOpen");
    $("#DetailsRow"+i+" .hgDate").toggleClass("gameRowOpen");
    $("#DetailsRow"+i+" .hgGameTimeThemeGiveaway").toggleClass("gameRowOpen");
    $("#DetailsRow"+i+" .hgGameTheme").toggleClass("gameRowOpen");
    $("#DetailsRow"+i+" .hgMatchupBox").toggleClass("gameRowOpen");
    $("#DetailsRow"+i+" .hgMKEWaveBox, #DetailsRow"+i+" .hgOpponentBox").toggleClass("gameRowOpen");

    $("#DetailsRow"+i+" .hgMatchupBoxExpanded").toggleClass("gameRowOpen");
    $("#DetailsRow"+i+" .gameThemeAreaExpanded").toggleClass("gameRowOpen");
    });
    $('#DetailsBtn'+i).toggle(function () {
    $("#DetailsRow"+i+" .ticketMasterGameLink").fadeIn();
    }, function () {
    $("#DetailsRow"+i+" .ticketMasterGameLink").hide();
  });
```

So the above code will get any of the #DetailsBtn's, grab the number value from the id, and use it to display the data related to that number value.

Comment: Rather than assigning a class, if modifying the html is not possible for instance one could also use the selector '[id^=DetailsRow]' to match all elements with an ID starting with that.

Answer (score 1):

WOW!

Please optimize your code, remove those duplicated lines by using smarter selectors. Also consider toggling class just on the root element, not all its children as well.

The following code uses the for loop, plus it features an optimized version of your code:

```js
function set(i) {
  $("#DetailsBtn" + i).click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("gameRowOpen");
    $(this).find(".leftDatePantherHolder .hgDate .hgGameTimeThemeGiveaway  .hgGameTheme .hgMatchupBox .hgMKEWaveBox .hgOpponentBox").toggleClass("gameRowOpen");
  })
}

for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  set(i);
}
```

```css
.gameRowOpen {color: green}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="DetailsBtn0">CLICK ME</div>
<div id="DetailsBtn1">CLICK ME</div>
<div id="DetailsBtn2">CLICK ME</div>
```

---

I'm really not sure why none of the other answers suggested optimizing the code...

Comment: Totally on point about optimization. I guess no one else noticed because it seems to me like people are trying to post the answer as soon as possible (and I'm not better). However, I think that maybe a for loop wouldn't be appropriate here performance wise if there's like 100 IDs...and that part could be optimized using classes instead and basically having just 1 "click" event handler.

Comment: I agree on the first part, but I'm not so sure about the second... I still think a plain JS for loop would kill jQuery's class selectors speed-wise. Shall we test it?

Comment: If you're willing to test it out and share the insight, it's sure appreciated. You might have a point...

Comment: You were right - I totally neglected the additional jQuery selector in my code (thought it was just `JS for loop` vs `jQ class selector`). Added a pure JS way, which is the fastest, of course. See here: http://jsperf.com/js-for-loop-vs-jq-class-selector

Answer (score 0):

Put all your element's strings in an array, and then iterate over it, for example in your case this might be the solution :

```
var elements = ["#DetailsBtn79", "#DetailsBtn80"];

for (element in elements) {
    $(elements).click(function () {
        $(element).toggleClass("gameRowOpen");

        // ... rest of your treatment

        $(element + " .ticketMasterGameLink").hide();
    });
}
```

Comment: Why not just `for (var x = LOWER_LIMIT; x <= UPPER_LIMIT; x++) { var element = '#DetailsBtn' + x; /* etc */`.  No need to declare all the elements if it's just the index changing.  But I agree with @JAL - there will be a _much_ better way of structuring this with jQuery

Comment: Yeah, this is simpler. As we don't really know if `"#DetailsBtn79"` and `"#DetailsBtn80"` are the only elements, I thought there could also be some that aren't `#DetailsBtn`.

Comment: @ Protectator this is what I want to do, but in my case I do not know in advance how many DetailsBtns or DetailsRows there may be, it could be more than two, so basically the numeric portion would be dynamically changing.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can do it the same way as java/c#

```
for (var i = 79; i <=80; i++)
{
   $("#DetailsBtn"+i).click(function () {
   ...
   }
}
```